# PyCrypto AES-CFB with SCrypt and HMAC

Tags: python, python-2.x, security, authentication, aes

I am brushing up on my Python, and since I would like to learn a bit about encryption, I figured I would give PyCrypto a try. I obviously wouldn't implement encryption in any production environment, but I am curious to see if I made any obvious mistakes from a security perspective, and also if my code could be optimized or made more pythonic.

[PyCryptodome 3.4.6](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) 
[quantumrandom 1.9.0](https://github.com/lmacken/quantumrandom) 
[pyscrypt 1.6.2](https://github.com/ricmoo/pyscrypt)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import quantumrandom
import hmac
import hashlib
import pyscrypt

HMAC_KEY = "738525cf1f8acd06beb4cf6cd816d1dc"


class AuthenticationError(Exception):
    pass


def gen_key(password):
    """Derives a key from input string using SCrypt and returns it hex encoded."""   
    hashed = pyscrypt.hash(
        password=password,
        salt="2df2e24c76d4d7b37e7ffcdf787e426b",
        N=16384,
        r=8,
        p=1,
        dkLen=16)

    return hashed.encode('hex')


def encrypt(plaintext, password):
    """Takes plaintext input and returns hex encoded ciphertext
    with hex encoded HMAC-SHA-512 hash appended."""

    key = gen_key(password)
    iv = quantumrandom.binary()[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    data = iv.encode("hex") + cipher.encrypt(plaintext).encode("hex")
    sig = hmac.new(HMAC_KEY, data, hashlib.sha512).digest().encode("hex")

    ciphertext = data + sig

    return ciphertext


def decrypt(ciphertext, password):
    """Takes ciphertext and password input, splits it into MAC hash and message
    data, verifies the hash and returns message plaintext if successful."""

    sig = ciphertext[-128:]
    data = ciphertext[:-128]

    if hmac.new(HMAC_KEY, data, hashlib.sha512).digest().encode("hex") != sig:
        raise AuthenticationError("Message Authentication failed!")

    iv = data[:32].decode("hex")
    message = data[32:].decode("hex")
    key = gen_key(password)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

    return cipher.decrypt(message)


SHARED_SECRET = "correct horse battery staple"
plaintext = "If You're Typing the Letters A-E-S Into Your Code You're Doing It Wrong"
ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext, SHARED_SECRET)

print "Ciphertext:", ciphertext

print "Decrypted:", decrypt(ciphertext, SHARED_SECRET)
```

Comment: I assume `quantumrandom` is [quantumrandom 1.9.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantumrandom), maybe add a link?

Comment: @Coal_ That's right. I've added some links and version numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import quantumrandom
```

The problem is that you should not trust third parties when importing random numbers. Furthermore, getting the randomness requires a secure connection in the first place. The secure connection relies on random numbers to remain secure. A secure random number generator that has been seeded by the OS is generally the best way to go.

```
HMAC_KEY = "738525cf1f8acd06beb4cf6cd816d1dc"
```

Generally keys should not be strings, not even hexadecimal strings. Strings are easy to find. I'd rather even use a Python `\b` string than hexadecimals, but preferably you'd use a keystore, or keys derived from a password supplied by the user. Which brings us to the next point:

```
hashed = pyscrypt.hash(
    password=password,
    salt="2df2e24c76d4d7b37e7ffcdf787e426b",
    N=16384,
    r=8,
    p=1,
    dkLen=16)
```

Don't use single-person unmaintained libraries. Never ever use a static salt. A salt, again, is a binary string, not a normal string. 16Ki iterations is on the short scale of things.

```
iv = quantumrandom.binary()[:16]
```

If you'd have used a random salt for each encryption then you can simply derive the keys (the encryption and MAC key) *and* IV from it. As the salt is unique, the key and IV combination will be unique as well.

```
data = iv.encode("hex") + cipher.encrypt(plaintext).encode("hex")
sig = hmac.new(HMAC_KEY, data, hashlib.sha512).digest().encode("hex")
```

I applaud you for having the IV authenticated as well. I also applaud you for using encrypt-then-MAC which is generally considered more secure than encrypt-and-MAC or MAC-then-encrypt.

I cannot applaud you to perform the HMAC over the hexadecimal representation of the bytes though; you've just doubled the required effort for calculating it. Never confuse binary with the *representation* of the binary in some textual format (hex, base64).

And while we're at it, hex requires an overhead of 100% when viewed as bytes (assuming an 8 bit encoding). Base 64 is a lot more efficient. Generally: first concatenate the binary, then encode; this will generate fewer characters as well. Or keep it as binary of course; a lot of ciphertext is encoded unnecessarily (leading to so called "stringified" code).

---

One improvement would be the use of an authenticated cipher such as AES-GCM instead of performing the encryption and HMAC separately.

For larger plaintext / ciphertext you could think about piecemeal updates / streaming so that the entire plaintext / ciphertext doesn't need to be in memory all at once.